# Drag and Drop email to Desktop

Tags: high-sierra, email, mojave, desktop

When I drag and drop an email to the Desktop it always moves to the top right (or the first free space near the top right).  I want it to stay where I dropped it.

When I drag and drop a file from a Finder window to the desktop the file does drop where I place it.

This is with both Mojave and High Sierra and I do have "Sort by None" in the Desktop preferences.

How to I get Apple Mail to drop a message where I place it on the Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

I use the Desktop > Sort by ...

`Snap to Grid` option

and Mail stays where I placed it

The sort by name does what you observe.

Comment: I wish it was as simple as that.  Snap to Grid doesn't change the behaviour I see.  The problem is only for Mail messages.  Files dragged to the desktop stay where I put them.

Comment: @Gilby I was talking about Mail messages, they do stay where placed

Answer (score 0):

right click on the desktop and go to show view options. to do what you want to have, I did sort by none and stacks by none.

[image: Show view options]

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  But not the answer.  I suspect it is something to do with Apple Mail, not Desktop's settings.

Comment: the issue is that @buskar and I are unable to recreate the issue you said. It works just fine with what the image says posted in my answer.

Comment: I appreciate that you and @Buscar are unable to reproduce. And I do use the view option suggested. The issue is only with whole messages from Apple Mail.  Attachments drop correctly.  I will try some more.

Comment: It I drag and drop a Mail message to another folder and then drag and drop to the Desktop: the message stays where I put it.  The issue really is only dragging a message from Mail to Desktop.